# Apply 'positive' style to a percentage if positive - pulled from Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, html, css, numbers, percentage

I pull data (both numbers and %) in from Google Sheets using ID's. I am trying to applying styling using Javascript that colors the data green if positive and red if it's negative. My Javascript work's perfectly for numbers but not for percentages.

codepen: https://codepen.io/liamdthompson/pen/YbQRgv

```
    divs.forEach(function(div){
        // Convert text to number and test for positive/negative
        if((+div.textContent) >= 0){
        div.classList.add("positive"); // Apply positive style
        } else {
        div.classList.add("negative"); // Apply negative style  
        }
    });  
    });
```

```
.positive {
  color: green;
}
```

```
.negative {
  color: red;
}
```

This currently results in the number '10.2' being displayed in green, but the percentage '2.00%' displayed in black (where the styling isn't working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extra condition to check if `%` exist in the coming value or not then handle it accordingly.

```
         if(div.textContent.includes('%')){
              div.textContent = div.textContent.split('%')[0];
            }
```

Check updated snippet

```css
.positive {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="" id="QStreak"></div>
<div id="QStreak1"></div>

<!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      
 


  function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)  {

  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
      callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  
  }


  httpGetAsync ('https://spreadsheet.glitch.me/?key=1mT_ILqpPtoCnWq5fEcBbVcgkKxcXN6uS9F2fsAO7imI', function(response) {
  var json = JSON.parse(response);

 //QStreak
      document.getElementById("QStreak").innerHTML = json[6].ThisWeek;
  document.getElementById("QStreak1").innerHTML = json[6].PriceChange;
 
  let divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#QStreak, #QStreak1"));



  // Loop the array
    divs.forEach(function(div){
        // Convert text to number and test for positive/negative
        let num = div.textContent;
        if(div.textContent.includes('%')){
           
          div.textContent = div.textContent.split('%')[0];
        }
      
        if((+div.textContent) >= 0){
        div.classList.add("positive"); // Apply positive style
        } else {
        div.classList.add("negative"); // Apply negative style  
        }
        div.textContent = num;
    });  
    });

  
  </script>
```

Comment: So it can only detect if the number is greater than 0 if I remove the '%'? The correct colouring is now applied but I am losing the % symbol to do it. Is there a way to  keep the % symbol? Possibly by re-adding it to the number after it has had the .positive class assigned? Thanks I appreciate your help!

Comment: No, It will detect both -ve and +ve numbers as per your code. Yes, I have updated the snippet to keep the % symbol in the values.